# DjangoAdmin: Accesing the parent instance within an Inline admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, admin

I have a Django admin class which declares an inlines iterable. Something like:

```
@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    ...
    inlines = [CategoryModifiersInline,]
    ...
    ...
```

Then I have an Inline admin class like this:

```
class CategoryModifiersInline(admin.TabularInline):

    model = Category.modifiers.through
    fk_name = 'category'
    extra = 1 


    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        qs = Product.objects.filter(is_modifier=True).filter(active=True)
        kwargs['queryset'] = qs
        return super(CategoryModifiersInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Where I filter the queryset for the foreign key based on some business requirement.

This inline is only showed to the user in the `change` view, that means, when an object of the class Category is created and the user wants to add modifiers to it, never in the `add` view.

What I want to do, is filtering the foreign key by one of the attributes of the Category model, I mean, I want to access the parent object from the `formfield_for_foreignkey` method.

Does anyone know a way to achieve that?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12053145/633961

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41065115/1170195) here in StackOverflow, and used the method described there to solve it.

It uses the `parent_model` attribute from inlines, and the `resolve` method from `django.core.urlresolvers` to get the instance based in the url.

Here's the code:

```
    def get_object(self, request):
        resolved = resolve(request.path_info)
        if resolved.args:
             return self.parent_model.objects.get(pk=resolved.args[0])
        return None
```

Then I would call the `get_object` method inside of my `formfield_from_foreignkey` method to get the instance of the object I want to use as a filter.

Hope it helps!