# Django Admin - Filter inline content depending on parent value

Tags: django, django-admin

I have to models: "Order" and "Product"; the "Order" contains a "Customer" as foreign key.
I create an admin page where Order is the parent and products are shown as inline.

When I add a new istance of products I want that a dropdown is filtered based on the value chosen in the parent "Customer" field.

I've already tried the chained dropdown list with no success; I've also overriden the **init** method of the inline form but the result is the same. I can't understand what is the metod triggered when I click the "add new" link in inline formset.

Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve the result?

Comment: If you are using Django Admin you can override Admin.change_view to filter values based on some model. In older versions of Django you could override formfield_for_foreignkey.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12053145/633961